# Possible to add udf wrapper to this dataframe operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var result_df1 = result_df.select(result_df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)): _ * )
```

This is my dataframe operation I am performing.  I have a udf called `EmptyToNull` that takes in one paramter, a value, checks if it is empty, if so, it changes it to null.  Is it possible to call this UDF in this dataframe operation I am already performing?

Answer (score 0):

Function "col" can be wrapped by UDF:

```
// functions
val emptyToNull : (String) => String = (value: String) => if(StringUtils.isBlank(value)) null else value
val emptyToNullUDF = udf(emptyToNull)

// usage
val result_df= List(("NonEmpty"," ") ).toDF("nonempty","empty")
    val result_df1 = result_df.select(result_df.columns.map(c => emptyToNullUDF(col(c)).alias(c).cast(StringType)): _ * )
result_df1.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----+
|nonempty|empty|
+--------+-----+
|NonEmpty|null |
+--------+-----+
```

**Note:** "alias" is used for preserve column names. Also, if original columns has StringType, clause ".cast(StringType)" is not required.